# Date logic puzzle: calculating UTC equivalent to yesterday local time at 8 AM

Tags: algorithm, date, momentjs

Banging my head on this simple date logic problem:

I know the user's time zone offset relative to UTC.

My server is in UTC. It knows the time now.

How do I calculate UTC equivalent of 'yesterday local time at 8am'?

IN JS, I tried to do it this, but it seems to not quite work.

```
var yesterday_am=moment(moment(new Date()).subtract(24,'hour')).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // same local time previous day;
// when is 8am local time in utc?
var am=8 - (user.tz_offset/60);
if (am<0) { yesterday_am=moment(yesterday_am).subtract(Math.abs(am), 'hour')};
if (am>0) { yesterday_am=moment(yesterday_am).add(am, 'hour')};
```

For example, if UTC is `2016-01-10 0235` and local time is -7 hours, it would output `2016-1-09 1500` (8am local).

Comment: I thought this should be an arithmetic problem. Where is the logic part?

Comment: The logic part is, I don't know if it is a logic problem or an arithmetic problem. Calculating between local and UTC confuses me a lot.

Comment: Could you add an example? What should be the output if the current UTC time is `2016-01-10 0800`?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: What you are trying to do cannot be done. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***This code is not DST aware*** (in case if you've not already figure out based on the comments below). Thank you Maggie. Please refer to complete answer from Maggie.

You can do something like this

```
var localTime = moment.utc("2016-06-19").utcOffset('-07:00');
var utcAt8PrevDay = moment(localTime).subtract(1,'days').startOf('day').add(8, 'hour').utc();
```

Comment: Perfect. I had no idea `startOf` method was available! Awesome!

Comment: This code does not handle DST transitions for several reasons, and is not the proper way to make this calculation with Moment.js. If the offset today is -7, and the offset yesterday was -8 due to DST, this code will not work. In addition, if the clock 'sprang forward' at 2 am, then adding 8 hours will land you at 9 am.

Comment: OP has the offset, so I thought he'll have the right offset (includes DST when applicable). Is my understanding not correct ? If no, please help me change it to DST aware.Shall I use the timezone instead ? Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I don't want to be harsh when I call posts wrong - this mistake just gets made a lot with date and time :-)

Comment: no worries. Thank you for taking your time to respond. I'm glad it helps the OP and trust me last thing I want is to mislead OP with my incorrect understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The logic you are trying to perform is impossible. Without knowing the user's actual time zone, you cannot know the UTC equivalent of 'yesterday at 8 am' local time. Daylight saving time transitions may make the offset yesterday different than the offset today. See the [time zone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), particularly the Time Zone != Offset section for more information.

If you do know the user's time zone, then you can perform this calculation using the [moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) add-on library for Moment.js. The code would be as follows:

```
moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles').subtract(1, 'day')
.set({hours:8, minutes:0, seconds:0, milliseconds:0}).utc()
```

Breaking this down so it makes sense, we are doing the following things:

```
moment() //get the current time
.tz('America/Los_Angeles') //put the moment in the Los Angeles time zone
//the Los Angeles time zone is one of several that are UTC-7 right now
.subtract(1, 'day') //go to yesterday
.set({hours:8, minutes:0, seconds:0, milliseconds:0}) //set the time to exactly 8 am
.utc() //convert back to UTC
```

Do not add 8 hours to the start of the day. This will be 9 AM if the clocks 'sprang forward' that day, and 7 am if they 'fell back'.

It sounds like your code is running in Node on the server. If it is running in the browser, then the browser knows the user's time zone rules, and you could use the following code to get the time at 8 am yesterday:

```
moment().subtract(1, 'day').set({hours:8, minutes:0, seconds:0, milliseconds:0}).utc()
```

This code does not require the moment timezone add on because the browser knows the time zone rules for the user's local time.

If you need to get the user's time zone, you have a few options. The most reliable is to use a timezone picker built into a map to let the user choose. There are a few of these floating around the internet.

If you do not want to do that, you can use the `moment.tz.guess()` function to have moment timezone make an educated guess about the user's time zone using some heuristics. This function is good, but due to limitations of the browser it is impossible to make it 100% accurate.

For a whole bunch of information about handling date and time and time zones in JavaScript, you can try [this talk I did at JavaScript MN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieIzNP6gKqU) a few months ago.

In addition, you might like [this really excellent Pluralsight course by Matt Johnson](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/date-time-fundamentals).

Comment: I thought a simple `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` would takes into account both timezone and DST. Why is it impossible?

Comment: Because that is the offset only for that particular point in time.  `new Date()` gives the current date and time, so `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` gives the *current* offset.